# Trabajando con varios argumentos en una funcion de JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro estancado en un ejercicio, especificamente en el 04-removeArray de The Odin Project. La idea es por medio de 1 o 2 argumentos eliminar un elemento de un array. Por ejemplo, si como argumento pongo 2 y 4 deberia eliminar los elementos con ese mismo numero (los elementos dentro del array son los numeros del 1 al 5).

Ya consegui hacerlo funcionar con un solo parametro pero no consigo dar con una manera de que funcione con dos.

```
const removeFromArray = function(array, elementA) {
    let arrayHolder = [];
    arrayHolder = array;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayHolder.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === elementA) {
            arrayHolder.splice(elementA - 1, 1)
            return arrayHolder;
        }
    }
};

removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
```

Cualquier, consejo o explicacion es bienvenido.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Splice eimina por indice, no por elemento ;)

Comment: Supongo que no puedes usar funciones o métodos de Array para lograrlo, o si? Porque si es un ejercicio académico, seguramente no sea posible usarlos.

Comment: Por otro lado, hacer esto: `let arrayHolder = array` **no copia** el contenido de `array` en `arrayHolder`, sino que crea un nuevo *puntero* a la misma dirección de memoria de `array`. Así,  todo lo que modifiques en uno se verá reflejado en el otro y viceversa, ya que estarás modificando el mismo objeto en memoria.

Comment: ese "removeFromArray" que estás mostrando no funciona, curiosamente de la forma incorrecta que hiciste funciona con el número 3 como segundo argumento pero si pasas otro número veras que no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función .filter()

```
    const removeFromArray = function(array, ...elementsToRemove) {
    return array.filter(item => !elementsToRemove.includes(item));
};

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 4));
```

Comment: Podrias explicarme cual es proceso detras de este codigo? En verdad soy algo nuevo en esto aun. Y muchas gracias!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).